# Newlines with preg_match_all

Tags: php, html-parsing, preg-match, newline, preg-match-all

I am trying to capture all occurrences of `<col width="NUMBER">` using `preg_match_all`. I got it to work without newlines, but can't with them. I've used the /s modifier at the end, but no go.

Note, initially I could only return the first occurrence but I found that I could use an assertion which gave me all occurrences using`(?=<col width=[^>](.*)>)`

```
// without newlines in text, it finds 88 and 573
    $text = '<table><colgroup><col width="88"><col width="573"></colgroup>';

    preg_match_all('/<col width=[^>](.*)>(?=<col width=[^>](.*)>)/si', $text, $acell);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($acell);
    echo "</pre>";    

// with newlines in text, can't find it.
    $text = '<table>
    <colgroup><col width="88">
    <col width="573">
    </colgroup>';

    preg_match_all('/<col width=[^>](.*)>(?=<col width=[^>](.*)>)/si', $text, $acell);    
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($acell);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: There are newlines after the `>`, not within. And the assertion just works by accident there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler:

```
preg_match_all('/<col width=[^>]+>/i', $text, $acell);
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the above text that has newlines. Nothing is matched - not even the first occurrence.

Comment: Sure it does: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf202dc36f39236ddd71fe57ff9af0db320fd50e

Comment: Very strange - I see it work in the sandbox, but it still gives nothing on my local machine - cut and pasted into a new php file.

Comment: OK, it wouldn't show the content of the cells because the browser is rending the tags. That is why I use `var_dump` with output - it shows that the strings have length. Is there a way to get output with tags to show in firefox with `print_r`?

Comment: The `pre` tags should do that, but I use `highlight_string(print_r($acell, true));`

Comment: Actually, my original pattern was `preg_match_all('/<col width=[^>](.*)>/is', $text, $acell)` (similar to yours). Because of your answer, I found that by removing the s modifier, it works. Interesting. Why does adding the s modifier: `preg_match_all('/<col width=[^>]+>/is', $text, $acell);` break your answer?